# orderBy when change a value from the array angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have something like this:

```
[
  {name: 'Julian', number: 1},
  {name: 'Mike', number: 2},
  {name: 'Carlos', number: 3},
  {name: 'Juan', number: 4},
  {name: 'Kate',number: 5},
]
```

and an orderBy: 'number' in a ng-repeat. It is working perfect but I need to exchange that values of numbers, for example now I need that Juan has a number 2 and Mike has a number 4, and then I need them to reorder. I have a filter before that and the filter is receiving the correct change but then when it orderBy the number I don't know why it is ordering as the first time it oredered. It isn't taking in account that the number value had changed.

Anyone knows about a solution ?

Edited:

Here is an example of a kind of what I want to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/eWZHh/9/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a demo and it looks it works fine. You can see the data is changed in 2 seconds and the data and order filter will be updated automatically.

**Edit**: You need to put the ng-click button inside the controler's scope

```
<ul ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="changeOrder()">Change order</button>
    <li ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy: 'number'">{{ user.name }}, {{ user.number }}</li>
</ul>
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eWZHh/10/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems to work for you but take a look at my example please :) You reentered all the data, I only changed the values.

Comment: The button is outside the controler's scope, you need to put it inside

Comment: Oh you were right, sorry. It is working, but I don't know why in my application it doesn't work :/ I used drag and drop and more things, i will have to take a look for other things, thanks :)